# jquery append doesnt include bootstrap style after adding

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jquery script

```
$('.add-item').on('click',function(){
    var URL = '{% url "main:adding_from_all_products" %}';
    var $this = $(this);
    var product_add_name = $this.data('item-name');
    $.post(URL,{'product_add_name':product_add_name},function(response){
        $(".test").append('<p class="product-item">'+
                            '<span class="product-width-fix">' +
                            response +
                            '<a href="#" data-product-id=' + product_add_name +
                            'class="btn btn-mini btn-success remove-product">Remove</a></span></p>');
    })
    return true;
});
```

The element I add is a button styled with bootstrap. But after the append is done

```
<a href="#" data-product-id=' + product_add_name +
                                    'class="btn btn-mini btn-success remove-product">Remove</a></span></p>
```

the button does not apper, it's just a link withouth any style. what should i do ?

Comment: Add space before class.`'<a href="#" data-product-id=' + product_add_name +' class="btn btn-mini btn-success remove-product">Remove</a></span></p>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you need `""` for `product_add_name` :

```
$(".test").append('<p class="product-item">'+
                                    '<span class="product-width-fix">' +
                                             response +
                                    '<a href="#" data-product-id="' + product_add_name +
                                    '" class="btn btn-mini btn-success remove-product">Remove</a></span></p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".test").append('<p class="product-item">' +
                  '<span class="product-width-fix">' + response +
                  '<a href="#" data-product-id=' + product_add_name +
                  ' class="btn btn-mini btn-success remove-product">Remove</a></span></p>');
```

there is no space between `product_add_name` and the `class`

Comment: changed that, now the button doesn't appear at all

Comment: Will you be able to put an alert(response) or console.log(response) within the callback function and see what are you getting as the response?

Comment: As a responce i get django model oblect it's certainly correct

Comment: Sorry, I just have asked to log the wrong element. Please log and see what "product_add_name" is. This can be happen if your "product_add_name" which is returned by "$this.data('item-name')" is having any incompatible character.

Comment: i can't test the code now, but when I can ill reply. product_add_name is returns a number

Answer (score 0):

I just checked this with code,

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){
  var response="The Product Name";
  var product_add_name="productName";

  $(".test").append('<p class="product-item">'+
        '<span class="product-width-fix">' +response +
        '<a href="#" data-product-id=' + product_add_name +
    ' class="btn btn-mini btn-success remove-product"> Remove </a></span></p>');
  });
</script>
</head>
<body><div class="test"></div></body>
</html>
```

This works fine even if you didn't use "" for "product_add_name" like `data-product-id="'` instead of `data-product-id='` and `'" class=...` instead of `' class...` (But if you have spaces in product_add_name, you need to use "" in order to get the expected output).

Please log and see what `"product_add_name"` is. This can be happen if your `"product_add_name"` which is returned by `"$this.data('item-name')"` is having any incompatible character.

If your `"product_add_name"` is also valid, just check whether you are adding this child element

to a valid parent with style `display:block` applied.